# Expectation and Variance of linear transformation of multivariate random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance

[Calculation of expectation and variance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sykpa.png)

I've been reading "Mathematics for Machine Learning: https://mml-book.com."  In the book, I couldn't see the deviation of multivariate expectation (6.50) and variance (6.51).  They seem to be calculated based on the definition of the mean and covariance.

I would like to appreciate if anybody helps me understand this.